# Can't find the replacement for EntryPoint Attribute in .net 4.7

Tags: c#, .net, solidworks

So i am trying to update the solidoworks macro from .net 3.5 to .net 4.7

And when i was about to do that, i found that there is a method called `EntryPoint(0)` which basically is the start point for the macro code.

Adding the code below:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Contract;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools;
using SolidWorks;
using SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks;
using System;
using static System.Reflection.MethodInfo; 
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.AddIn.Contract.Collections; 
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Management;
using System.Runtime;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GoPublish.csproj
{
    public sealed class SolidWorksMacro : OuterDispProxy
    {
      [EntryPoint(0)]
      public SldWorks swApp;

      [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
      private static extern int CreateItemMoniker([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpszDelim, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpszItem, out IMoniker ppmk);

      [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
      private static extern int GetRunningObjectTable(uint reserved, out IRunningObjectTable pprot);
```

I am not able to find a replacement of that in the .net 4.7

Any suggestions as to how can i do that?

Comment: Can you target for Net 3.5?  Check installed software and see if Net 3.5 is installed.

Comment: @jdweng Yes the system has 3.5 installled. And it works perfect for 3.5. But for windows 10 machines, there is 4.7 installed for default and we want to target for that only. Because when we upgrade the solidworks software, the macro stops working.

Comment: @WaiHaLee I added the code for the macro, the import statements and the `EntryPoint(0)` part as well.

Comment: Microsoft does not release each class in Net Library when it does a new release.  Only methods that change.  So you need to install older version of Net to get all method to run.  Also see Solidworks : https://help.solidworks.com/2018/English/api/sldworksapi/SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks~SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks_namespace.html?id=57ef3018c51e443eb0e2f5c1dc273043

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class EntryPointAttribute is defined in the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Contract.dll, which is a part of VSTA (Visual Studio Tools for Applications). I'm not too familiar with it but my understanding it's a lightweight version of VS for macro/plugin development.

You definitely can build solidworks macros without this dll, but there are a lot of ways to build macros, so maybe with your specific setup you do need it.

I'm guessing you've been using VSTA for your 3.5 version and switched to VisualStudio for 4.7 and that's your actual issue.

.net 4.7 has full support for the libraries build for previous versions, so you can try adding the reference manually. Here's where I was able to find Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Contract.dll : C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Contract\8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Contract.dll

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked. I was adding the contract files v9.0 and v10.0 in the references but not the one you mentioned.  Can you also tell me how to make .swp file from .csproj. Any ideas?

Comment: swp is a different type of macro, just use dll that visual studio builds for you

Comment: read here about different types of SW macro https://www.codestack.net/solidworks-api/getting-started/macros/types/